# Running containers on RPi with buildroot: problems with CNI

Tags: docker, buildroot, container

I'm currently trying to get containers to run on my RPi (CM4 module) using buildroot.

I've configured the kernel and additional packages such that I should be able to run containers. I can verify that `containerd` is running correctly, by having it run in a terminal. At the same time I can execute the following:

```
ctr run --no-pivot --rm docker.io/library/hello-world:latest test
```

this works, and I get the hello-world message

However when running a more ambitious container, I'm getting an error:

```
ctr run --no-pivot --rm -t --net-host docker.io/library/nginx:1.21 nginx
```

Output:

```
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Enabled listen on IPv6 in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
2023/01/23 11:09:36 [emerg] 1#1: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2023/01/23 11:09:36 [notice] 1#1: try again to bind() after 500ms
2023/01/23 11:09:36 [emerg] 1#1: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2023/01/23 11:09:36 [notice] 1#1: try again to bind() after 500ms
2023/01/23 11:09:36 [emerg] 1#1: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2023/01/23 11:09:36 [notice] 1#1: try again to bind() after 500ms
```

This is due to another service running on port 80. If I stop that service, it kinda works:

```
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Enabled listen on IPv6 in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
2023/01/23 12:42:51 [notice] 1#1: using the "epoll" event method
2023/01/23 12:42:51 [notice] 1#1: nginx/1.21.6
2023/01/23 12:42:51 [notice] 1#1: built by gcc 10.2.1 20210110 (Debian 10.2.1-6) 
2023/01/23 12:42:51 [notice] 1#1: OS: Linux 5.10.110-v8
2023/01/23 12:42:51 [notice] 1#1: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1024:1024
2023/01/23 12:42:51 [notice] 1#1: start worker processes
2023/01/23 12:42:51 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 31
2023/01/23 12:42:51 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 32
2023/01/23 12:42:51 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 33
2023/01/23 12:42:51 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 34
```

But the problem is: I still have to free up port 80.

Now, I'd like to map that port elsewhere, for instance to port 8080.

I tried doing that with `nerdctl`(which I've also configured with buildroom compilation before), but I'm getting this error:

```
# nerdctl run --rm -it --name nginx -p 80:8080 docker.io/library/nginx:1.21
FATA[0001] failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error running hook #0: error running hook: exit status 1, stdout: , stderr: time="2023-01-23T13:45:04+01:00" level=fatal msg="failed to call cni.Setup: plugin type=\"bridge\" failed (add): running [/usr/sbin/iptables -t nat -A CNI-40513ffc80d158b3c3937c5b -d 10.4.0.18/24 -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment name: \"bridge\" id: \"default-9c651b466d3604dfe46ace174f0cb61634ab731d560428d10475b357016d79e3\" --wait]: exit status 1: Warning: Extension comment revision 0 not supported, missing kernel module?\niptables: No chain/target/match by that name.\n"
Failed to write to log, write /var/lib/nerdctl/1935db59/containers/default/9c651b466d3604dfe46ace174f0cb61634ab731d560428d10475b357016d79e3/oci-hook.createRuntime.log: file already closed: unknown
```

Now, in order to even get this far, I had to not only enable CNI plugins. `host-local` was missing from `/opt/cni/bin/`, so I downlaoded this: https://github.com/containerd/containerd/releases/download/v1.6.15/cri-containerd-cni-1.6.15-linux-arm64.tar.gz, and extracted `/opt/cni/bin/host-local`, as well as `/etc/cni/net.d/10-containerd-net.conflist`.
Both were not available inside the buildroot suite. Even so, when trying to adjust the configuration in `/etc/cni/net.d/10-containerd-net.conflist` it still ain't working. I have no further CNI modules I could compile into buildroot.

This is where I'm stuck.

What am I missing here? `iptables` are enabled in buildroot, too, so that shouldn't be an issue.

My goal is to be able to run containers on a RPi CM4 on an environment made with buidroot, such that I can map the ports freely, etc.

I know that I can't map ports with `ctr` or `runc`, hence I tried using `nerdctl` (predominantly because it was available as a module in buildroot)

*(tagged with 'docker', because generic container tag is not available)*